# php using exec output as array and iterate over

Tags: php

I am stuck on this.. I am a perl programmer and trying to use php has gotten me stuck on this one issue. I want to run a system command(or whatever script I have) and use the output as array and loop it through.

For an example

```
exec("/bin/myScript.pl $criteria1", $outputArray);

foreach ($item as $outputArray) {
    print $item . "<br />";
}
```

I am not sure why above do not work. When I do print_r($outputArray), I see the results, but I want to iterate through them and do whatever I need to do. What am I missing? OR am I looking at this from NONE php perspective?

Please help

Comment: When in doubt: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

You are using `foreach` in the wrong way:

```
exec("/bin/myScript.pl $criteria1", $outputArray);

foreach ($outputArray as $item) { // <------
    print $item . "<br />";
}
```